# Add filter to a Extjs grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I want to add some filters to my grid when I clicked on the filter button (see below).The filters must be add tot the grid with the given values from the filterpanel form.

On this page the textfield will be filled in and when I clicked on the filter button the onFilterClick handler will trigger the FilterController.

```
Ext.define('path.to.filterPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

xtype: 'filter',
controller: 'dashboard-filter',

viewModel: { 
    type: 'dashboard-filter' 
},

frame: false,
bodyPadding: 10,
layout: 'form',

// the fields 
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'firstName',
    id: 'firstName',
    fieldLabel: 'Firstname'
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'lastName',
    id: 'lastName',
    fieldLabel: 'Lastname'
}],

 buttons: [
    text   : 'Filter',
    handler: 'onFilterClick' // trigger to the controller
}]
});
```

When clicked on the Filterbutton the values will be pust to this controller.

```
Ext.define('path.to.FilterController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.dashboard-filter',

onFilterClick: function(button) {

    var form = button.up('form').getForm();

    if (form.isValid()) {
        // form valid 

        var firstName = Ext.getCmp("firstName").getValue();
        var lastName = Ext.getCmp("lastName").getValue();

        // check if there is some input
        if (!!employeeNumber || !!firstName || !!lastName) {


            // add filters but how??


        } 
    } else {
        // form not valid
        console.log("not valid");
    }
}
});
```

Finally this is the grid file where the filters must be added.

```
Ext.define('path.to.gridPanel, {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

requires: [
    'Ext.grid.column.Action',
    'App.store.Employees'
],

controller: 'dashboard-gridVieuw',
xtype: 'gridVieuw',
store: 'Employees',

stateful: true,
collapsible: true,
multiSelect: true,

stateId: 'gridController',

initComponent: function () {
    this.store = new App.store.Employees();
    var me = this;

    me.columns = [{
        header   : 'Firstname',
        flex     : 1,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex: 'firstName'
    }, {
        header   : 'Lastname',
        flex     : 1,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex: 'lastName'
    }]

me.callParent();
}
});
```

I use version 5 of extjs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filterBy` method to filter the underlying `store` associated with the `grid`.  Here is an example:

```
Ext.getStore('myStore').filterBy(function(record, id) {
            if (record.get('firstName') === firstName) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating a working example of a filter](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mj9)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering my question. It works for me. I've added the follow OnClick handler in the controller.

```
 onFilterClick: function(button) {

    var form = button.up('form').getForm();

    if (form.isValid()) {

        var fieldOne = Ext.getCmp("fieldOne").getValue();
        var fieldTwo = Ext.getCmp("fieldTwo").getValue();

        // check if there is some input
        if (!!fieldOne || !!fieldTwo) {

            // get store
            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('store');

            // check if store not empty
            if(!Ext.isEmpty(store)){
                // clear filters and add a few new filters if params not empty
                store.clearFilter(true);

                if (!Ext.isEmpty(fieldOne)) {
                    store.filter("fieldOne",  fieldOne)
                }

                if (!Ext.isEmpty(fieldTwo)) {
                    store.filter("fieldTwo",  fieldTwo)
                }

                // count the filtered rows
               var count = store.snapshot ? store.snapshot.length : store.getCount();

                if (count == 0) {
                    alert("No data found!");
                    store.clearFilter();    
                }
            } else{
                //Store empty
                console.warn("Store's empty");
            }
        } else {
            // no values 
            alert("No entered data!");
        }
    } else {
        // form not valid
        alert("Form not valid!");
    }
}
```